# Which vampire movie starts out showing a staked skeleton, then shows the internal organs reforming around the stake?

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I don't remember anything else about the movie, but that scene stuck in my mind.

Comment: Movies are not my forte, but I recall this scene from the start of a Hammeresque vampire film from the 70s. I think a sidekick had just poured blood into Dracula's coffin, where his ashes lay, and the body rebuilt as you describe. When the body was reconstructed Dracula's (Christopher Lee?) first action was to pull out and throw away the stake.

Comment: If it wasn't a stake, I would be thinking of [Frank's regeneration](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pWD23_pyOGU) in Hellraiser.

Comment: Thank you most kindly for your answer John Rennie!

Comment: I saw the same movie. It has eaten at me (pun intended) for decades. The coffin was an exhibit in a side show. It was propped up. A gloved hand reached in from off camera and pulled out the stake. Organs started re-forming. That's all I remember as well.

Comment: I think I've seen it, too. There was something about Morocco? It may have originally been in Spanish or Italian.

Comment: Is my answer correct? If not is there anything else you would like me to add for you to accept it?

Comment: Didn't Dracula 2000 also have this?

Comment: This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Answer (score 7):

I think this was Dracula, Prince of Darkness

Have a look at the trailer here:

Or view the full movie here:

[Dailymotion Movie | Dracula: prince of darkness](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xlsd50_dracula-prince-of-darkness_shortfilms)

Comment: Thank you most kindly for your answer and your link Stefan!

Comment: Pretty sure you got it, I've been looking for this too. I believe Dracula ends up collecting the wolfman and Frankie's monster out of the ice under the castle where they last battled in "Frankenstein Meets the Wolf Man"(1943). "House of Frankenstein" (1944) was essentially its sequel. YAY! Thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

Per @user32992's *[stub](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/68101/20774)* of an answer, could you be referring to the classic 1944 thriller "[House of Frankenstein](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0036931/)"? Early in the film we see a stake being removed from Dracula's skeleton. His body then reforms (complete with circulatory system and muscles) as we watch.

Please note the original effect was much better. I've heavily edited the clip for brevity.

[image]

Comment: Hmm, this is just the bare bones of an answer, wonder if you could flesh it out a bit more?

Comment: @RobertF - That's so funny, I'm having a coffin fit.